# Making navbar responsive

Tags: html, css

I am facing an issue with making my navbar responsive - if I change the default height of the navbar in the topnav class and resize my screen, the other menu options disappear in the small screen view.
I need help to fix this -

Below is my code:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
```

```css
<style>body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #001a33;
  height: 2.5rem;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {
    position: relative;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}

</style>
```

```html
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

And I also want to align the text in the center of the total height of the navbar ( right now it is touching the bottom of the bar)

I need help to fix these two issues. Thanks in advance !!

Comment: i dont think your using bootstrap. check this for bootstrap https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/navbar/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've already provided the answer but still If you're not getting how to change where to change here is your complete code with new changes. You can use this code. :)

```
<style>
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color:#001a33;
  height: auto;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: inline-block;}
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
</div>



<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with center text is because of height of nav bar, You made to 2.5rem but adding text size and padding making more height for A tag .

Make these two changes replace `.topnav` with below code

```
.topnav {
overflow: hidden;
background-color:#001a33;
height: auto;
}
```

and secondly change this code

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: inline-block;}
.topnav a.icon {
float: right;
display: block;
}
}
```

In `@media screen and (max-width: 600px)` change `display` to `inline-block`

Comment: Thank you for answering in so much detail ! I appreciate ! :)